# Compressing UIImage into JPEG image data multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage, jpeg

I am debugging a piece of code where an UIImage may be gone through UIImageJPEGRepresentation multiple times, I thought that must be a bug and the image quality will get worsen, but surprisingly we can't see the difference visually.

So I did a test, loading an image, and try to let it go through UIImageJPEGRepresentation 1000 times, surprisingly, whether 1 or 1000 times doesn't really make a difference in the image quality visually, why is that so?

This is the testing code:

```
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpeg"];

        // Create a data reference here for the for loop later
        // First JPEG compression here
        // I would imagine the data here already has low image quality
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0);

        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            // Convert the data with low image quality to UIImage
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            // Compress the image into a low quality data again
            // at this point i would imagine the image get even more low quality, like u resaved a jpeg twice in phootshop
            data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0);
        }

        // up to this point I would imagine the "data" has gone through JPEG compression 1000 times
        // like you resave a jpeg as a jpeg in photoshop 1000 times, it should look like a piece of crap
        UIImage *imageFinal = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageFinal];
        [self.view addSubview:view];

        // but it didn't, the final image looks like it has only gone through the jpeg compression once.
```

EDIT: my doubt can be summarised into a simpler code, if you do this in objectiveC:

```
        UIImage *image1 = an image..
        NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0);
        UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:data1];
        NSData *data2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0);
        UIImage *imageFinal = [UIImage imageWithData:data2];
```

Did imageFinal gone through JPEG compression twice?

Comment: what is the point of your loop if you are not using the loop value ? I am confused what you really want to do ? for the value zero it does but in your next step inside look you are not make data appending ? Can you explain more !

Comment: Hi I have edited my question, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: It would be interesting to try NSLog(@"%i", data.length). See if the compression reaches a limit.

Comment: if I NSLog data.length inside the for loop, the same length gets printed out 1000 times, looks like the data is not modified at all..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know, JPG compression works by altering the image to produce smaller file size. The reason why you don't see progressively worse quality is because you're using the same compression setting each time.

The algorithm alters the source image just enough to fit into the compression profile - in other words, compressing the result of 50% JPG again at 50% will produce the same image, because the image doesn't need to be altered any more.

You can test this in Photoshop - save a photo out at say 30% quality JPG. Reopen the file you just saved, and go to Save for Web - flip between PNG (uncompressed/original) and JPG 30% - there will be no difference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "To expand on this lets compress this sentence." this = 1 and en = 2. The sentence is now "To expand on 1 lets compress 1 s2t2ce." You can't keep compressing because there's nothing to compress! The same applies to image compression.

Comment: What happens if you compress with 90% of quality an image that was previously compressed with 50% quality?

Answer (score 1):

All types of compression will ideally reduce the size of an image.  There are two types of compression which describes how they affects images:

Lossy Compression:
Lossy compression will reduces the size of the image by removing some data from it. This generally cause, effect the quality of the image, which means it reduce your image quality

Lossless Compression:
Lossless compression reduce the size of the image by changing the way in which the data is stored.  Therefore this type of compression will make no change in the image quality.

Please check out the compression type you are using.

Comment: We know this, and this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you in decrease the image size. put the number from yourself how many times you want to perform loop;

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpeg"];

for(int i=100; i>0; i--)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, (0.1 * i);
    NSLog(@"%d",data.length);
}
```

Comment: i think my for loop example confused a lot of people here. I really just want to understand will UIImageJPEGRepresentation compress image multiple times if it is called multiple times. I do not need a for loop to compress image.

Comment: yes but you can implement this code for just checking. I checked that every time this decrease the NSData size in NSLog.just try it.